# Is it permissible for an intermediate proxy to add cookies during proxy authentication?

Tags: proxy, http, http-headers, cookie

I recently encountered a certain security appliance (BlueCoat) which requires that *all* connections to the internet must be proxied through it (hello there, man-in-the-middle) and accordingly uses a special SSL certificate to intercept all traffic.

This prevented the normal operation of Git, even though the appropriate `http.proxy` and `http.sslCAInfo` properties were set to make sure that the SSL connection itself works.

Using the environment variable `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`, we found that when using `git clone`, a HTTP 407 (Proxy authentication required) occurs. Git fulfils this authentication properly and at the end of this, the appliance returns a HTTP 200 with a cookie header `Set-Cookie`.

Git then will connect to the target server, but *without* the cookie, leading to a HTTP 401.

The solution for this is to set the git configuration option `http.saveCookies=true`

**Question:**
Is it actually permitted by the RFC standards that an intermediate proxy adds cookies?

Anthony Rich [asked the same question to the http-state mailing list](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/http-state/current/msg01179.html) but without any response. He did note that in

> RFC 2965 HTTP State Management Mechanism, 3.5  Caching Proxy Role it says:
> Proxies MUST NOT introduce Set-Cookie2 (Cookie) headers of their own
> in proxy responses (requests).

However, the [superseding RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) doesn't mention this anymore at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP cookies are a hot mess. There is no real standard; the RFC, for what it's worth, merely attempts to document what actual user agents are doing.

In any case, the RFC you probably want to read is [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.3), which specifies that proxies are supposed to send a Proxy-Authenticate header with the 407 status to request authentication information, and user agents receiving this are supposed to retry the request with a Proxy-Authorization header containing the authentication information for the proxy.

A number of challenge/response methods could be used to supply this information; the most widely used being "basic" ([RFC 7617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617)) as pretty much everything that speaks HTTP implements it.

The IANA maintains a [registry of known HTTP authentication schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml). As a general rule they use the HTTP headers named previously, or they are noted to be noncompliant. None use cookies for authentication.

Whether it's allowed for a proxy to add or change cookies, I can't say. The RFCs really don't seem to be very clear on this point. It's certainly *unexpected* behavior, especially for authentication. And BlueCoat has a long history of being mediocre in quality...